# How to convert data structure to another tree structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, data-structures, tree

I need your help for create a tree like data structure with given JSON as shown below and required output structure already given below. I am a beginner in programming and I have only a little knowledge in data structure

#### JSON from API

```
   [
    "",
    [
        "Test",
        [
            "Test/sample",
            [
                "Test/sample/sample1"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "Test/test3"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "Test1",
        [
            "Test1/test2"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "cat"
    ]
]
```

#### Output like below structure

```
 {
        "key": "Image",
        "label": "Image",
        "icon": 'pi pi-folder',
        "children": []
    },

    {
        "key": "Test",
        "label": "Test",
        "icon": "pi pi-folder",

        "children": [
            {
                "key": "Test/sample",
                "label": "Sample",
                "icon": "pi pi-folder",

                "children": [{
                    "key": "Test/sample/sample1",
                    "label": "Sample1",
                    "icon": 'pi pi-folder',
                    "children": []
                }]
            },
            {
                "key": "Test/test3",
                "label": "test3",
                "icon": "pi pi-folder",
                "children": []
            },
        ]
    },

    {
        "key": "Test1",
        "label": "Test1",
        "icon": "pi pi-folder",
        "children": [{
            "key": "Test1/test2",
            "label": "test2",
            "icon": "pi pi-folder",
            "children": []
        }]
    },

    {
        "key": "cat",
        "label": "cat",
        "icon": "pi pi-folder",
        "children": []
    },

]
```

Above structure is image file directory and directory name is indicated by label and icon is indicating directory, children show sub directory

[Console value of API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJk3r.png)

[image: Fig 1]

Comment: If possible, could you add some more info on the first JSON data (ie. each array seems to represent a prefix separated by '/' for its children, but thats a guess). Also, do you have any existing research/code you have done so far to help point you in the right direction?

Comment: @shameen when I fetch api I obtain the first JSON. Do you need console data

Comment: Can you provide full json input to your question?

Comment: @DoanVanThang above shows full JSON and console value of API added to the question

Comment: oh, I don't see key/value `Image` so I assume your JSON from API missing some value

Comment: @DoanVanThang the name `Image` is set conditionally when user can't select any folder its default set as image

Comment: Does my answer work?

Comment: @DoanVanThang I can't vote your answer because my reputation less than 15 and very very thanks for your help and brother how can solve  this type of problems in future what can I do for this

Comment: @DoanVanThang I have one more doubt how can we change above structure inside image folder children(image added above)

Comment: You can start by read article about recursive function like [this one](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/recursion). If you want to change structure, just edit `createChildNode` function

Comment: @DoanVanThang can you please just show how it will be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can easily archive with recursive function

```js
const icon = "pi pi-folder";
var a = [
    "",
    [
        "Test",
        [
            "Test/sample",
            [
                "Test/sample/sample1"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "Test/test3"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "Test1",
        [
            "Test1/test2"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "cat"
    ]
]

/**
 * @param {Array} arr The child array
 */
function createChildNode(arr) {
    let key = "Image";
    let label = "Image";
    let children = [];
    if (arr.length >= 1) {
        key = arr[0];
        label = key.includes("/") ? key.split("/").pop() : key;
        label = label.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + label.slice(1);
        for (let index = 1; index < arr.length; index++) {
            const element = arr[index];
            children.push(createChildNode(element));
        }
    }
    return {key: key, label: label, icon: icon, children: children};
}

var b = []
for (let index = 0; index < a.length; index++) {
    const element = a[index];
    b.push(createChildNode(element));
}
console.log(b);
```